# How to get the text using XPATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

```
<div class="Fz(12px) Px(8px) Mend(4px) Va(m) Bdrs(3px) C($c-fuji-grey-g) Bgc($c-fuji-grey-b) Cur(d) Py(3px)"><svg class="Mend(6px) Cur(d) Cur(p)" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="traffic" style="vertical-align: middle; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51); stroke: rgb(51, 51, 51); stroke-width: 0;"><path d="M35.826 11.728c-1.102.044-1.96.975-1.918 2.078.045 1.102.975 1.96 2.078 1.918l3.73-.15.014.015-10.033 10.033L19.6 15.527c-.78-.78-2.047-.78-2.827 0-.142.142-.25.302-.338.47-.168.09-.33.197-.47.34L.585 31.714c-.78.78-.78 2.047 0 2.828.392.39.904.586 1.415.586s1.024-.196 1.414-.587L18.187 19.77l10.07 10.068c.39.39.9.586 1.413.586s1.024-.195 1.414-.586c.11-.11.2-.23.28-.355.167-.09.327-.197.468-.34l10.71-10.71-.148 3.7c-.023.58.204 1.112.585 1.493.343.343.81.563 1.333.584 1.104.044 2.035-.815 2.078-1.918l.44-11.003-11.004.438z"></path></svg>Bullish</div>
```

I am trying to extract the text，'Bullish', using XPATH but it is not working out.

```
sentiment_search = '//*[@id="canvass-0-CanvassApplet"]/div/ul/li/div/div[3]/div/div/text()'
sentiment = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, sentiment_search).text
try:
    for i in range(len(posts)):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, sentiment_search)))
            if sentiment == 'Bullish': 
                 print('Bullish')
```

Comment: The DOM line you provided apparently has a lot of randomized attributes. The only static attribute looks like is `data-icon="traffic"`.  Also, it looks like it is enclosed in an `svg` element. it's difficult to narrow down the element without looking at the complete DOM that relates to this segment. If this is the only `svg` element in your page, then you may try `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']).text`. Also, instead of `presence_of_element_located`, try using `visibility_of_element_located` as sometimes element maybe present but not visible and hence extraction fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the text ***Bullish*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#canvass-0-CanvassApplet > div > ul > li > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > div"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="canvass-0-CanvassApplet"]/div/ul/li/div/div[3]/div/div"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "text()" in the xpath:

```
sentiment_search = '//*[@id="canvass-0-CanvassApplet"]/div/ul/li/div/div[3]/div/div'
```

and then get the text from the element:

```
sentiment = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, sentiment_search).text
```

*If there's only one element I suggest to use find_element instead of find_elements which returns list of all matching elements.*

Comment: i tried but it gives me: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Because find_elements returns a list of all matching elements to your xpath. That's why I suggested to use find_element (without the S) and if the element you're looking for isn't the first one add another condition in your xpath.